# Logout XFCE via Cron fails with "Could not get owner of name"

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, cron, logout

I am currently trying to make Xubuntu logout when the user is idle for 2 mins. However this doesn't work. I use the command *xfce4-session-logout --logout* which works perfectly from the command line, but when using cron I get the error

```
Could not get owner of name 'org.xfce.session manager' No such Name
```

I guess there is some environment variable missing or something like that, but Google didn't find anything. Can you help?

Best regards,
Philipp

System: Raspberry Pi 2

OS: Xubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer from ToZ from the Xfce forums:

> cron doesn't have access to your user's X or dbus environments. Here is one way to get xfce4-session-logout to run from a cron job:
>
> 1. Add to the end of your ~/.bashrc file, the following command:

```
    export | egrep "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS|DISPLAY" > ~/.xsession-export
```

> 2. Create a script to do the actual logout that incorporates those values:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    . $HOME/.xsession-export
    /usr/bin/xfce4-session-logout
```

> ...and make the script executable.
>
> 3. Call this script from your cron job.

In the meantime I found out it is also possible to end the session with (works also with lxsession for LXDE):

```
pkill -SIGTERM -f xfce4-session
```